# How can I get syntax highlighting for a .cu file in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, cuda, syntax-highlighting

I am studying CUDA based on the Visual Studio 2008. Could you please tell me how to make syntax highlighting appear in a .cu file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Follow these steps.

- Copy `usertype.dat` from `Program
  Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA CUDA
  SDK\doc\syntax_highlighting\visual_studio_8`
  to `Program Files\Microsoft Visual
  Studio 8\Common7\IDE`.
- Start Visual
  Studio and  go to `Tools -> Options
  -> Text Editor -> File Extension`
- In the extension box type "cu" and
  select "Microsoft Visual C++" in the
  drop down.
- Restart.

Answer (score 8):

Install Parallel Nsight, It will do it automatically.

Answer (score 3):

(Visual Studio 2015, v14.0)

1. Menu: Tools > Options
2. Sidebar: Text Editor > File Extension
3. Enter 'cu' for extension, select 'C++' for editor, click 'add'.
4. Re-open file with 'cu' extension