# How do I profile cuda project using Compute Visual Profiler without executable?

Tags: cuda, executable, profiler, nsight

So I got Visual Studio 2010 installed with NSight for VS. Projects are compiling and working just fine (but still I don't have intellisense recognized altough I spend many many hours and went through all tutorials).
Now I would like to use Compute Visual Profiler (NSight) to which I need executable. So when I go to Debug or Release after running the projest I can't find exe file there. How to create it ? 
Anyway I am able to run Compute Visual Profiler profiling this project by pointing the Debug directory but then I got the error :

```
Program run #18 completed.
Error : 
Application : "C:(...)dot_product.exe.intermediate.manifest".
Profiler data file 'C:/(...)temp_compute_profiler_0_0.csv' for application run 0 not found.
```

So my question is How could I possibly profile my project?

Comment: CUDA sdk provides some files for enabling VS to understand CUDA syntax: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077104/how-can-i-get-syntax-highlighting-for-a-cu-file-in-visual-studio . It is weird that you are not able to get an executable. Is there a problem in your build, or project configuration, errors etc?

Comment: There are no problems, build is successful, and I can run all projecets sucessfully. I have tried the link you write, it doesnt work for me.

Comment: Did you try these? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061565/setting-up-vs-2010-intellisense-for-cuda-kernel-calls and http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2010/10/visual-studio-2010-adding-intellisense-support-for-cuda-c/

Comment: I have tried the second one. I don't undestrand how to switch from the Runtime API to the Driver API as it is proposed in first link.

Comment: I could not understand what does he mean by switching to driver API. Does he mean using Driver API headers and functions? In C++11 the syntax, >>,  is recognized correctly, but in previous editions it is only valid in kernel calls, in .cu files..

Comment: You're getting some odd errors. I would try to reinstall everything. There's a good chance it will fix things, and save you a lot of time, as opposed to trying to fix individual problems with a broken install. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11332488/cuda-4-2-toolbox-vs2010/11347002#11347002

Comment: Nsight Visual Studio Edition Analysis Tools and the Visual Profiler are completely different tools. The Visual Profiler is an external application or can be used on Linux/Mac in Nsight Eclipse Edition. See [NVIDIA Parallel Nsight Vs Visual Profiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402775/nvidia-parallel-nsight-vs-visual-profiler) for a comparison of the two tools. If you are using Nsight VSE you can profile or trace your CUDA application by executing the command Nsight|New Analysis Activity.

Comment: In your question you are incorrectly specifying the application as the manifest file. Remove the ".intermeidate.manifest" from the application name and you should be fine.